# Why do people put value="Submit" for button element in a form if it won't be posted

Tags: html

I have seen people do:

```
<form ..>

  <button type='submit' value='Submit'>Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Why do they need `value='Submit'` if it isn't even submitted to the server? Is it for accessibility?

Comment: That's not important, it should be left out. The `type` attribute is what matters, it says "Hey, I'm a button, and I'm gon' submit this form to the `form-action`"

Comment: @DanielTheGeek — It doesn't really. `submit` is the default value.

Comment: Why people do something that has no practical effect is really a matter of opinion / speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Forms can have more than one submit button. If you also give each button a `name`, then you can use the value after submitting to see which one had been clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test submit</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" method="get">
   <button type='submit' name="clicked" value="thefirst">First</button>
   <button type='submit' name="clicked" value="thesecond">Second</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you submit this with the first button, the parameter posted will be `clicked=thefirst`, while with the second one it will be `clicked=thesecond`.

Of course in this case a much saner approach would be to give the buttons different *names*. but you get the idea.

Comment: Did you notice _if it won't be posted_

Comment: Sorry this does not answer the question of when there is only 1 submit button and there is no `name` field, but only a `value="Submit"` field.

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal I thought the OP meant the value of the button wasn't submitted when the button was clicked. Otherwise, why have a submit button at all.

Comment: @platypus If there is no name, you can still retrieve the value with JavaScript during validation, so it would still have some use. Or, in the particular case you're talking about, it could be a leftover from when the `<button>` was an `<input>` and the value was needed. After changing to a `<button>`, the value attribute wouldn't be caught by error checkers, so it would just be kept in.

Comment: @MrLister Actually question says why usually people write `value='Submit'` when it has no use to them.

Comment: @PraveshAgrawal The other answer already tries to address why people would do something that doesn't have any use. But it is heavily downvoted, so I didn't go there in my answer; I concentrated on when the value _would_ be used.

Answer (score 0):

All programmer use this. Because its is good understanding to another programmer to review already written code. It is not compulsory.